# How to sort table columns in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I implemented this following the Ryan Bates tutorial to `sort table columns` and it works great, however when I render the index page the table is already sorted by title (asc), and I would like to sort the columns only when the user click on the column header.

How could I achieve this?

**Code**

controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @products = Product.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end

  # ...

  private

  def sort_column
    Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
end
```

helper_method

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>
  <th><%= sortable "price" %></th>
  <th><%= sortable "released_at", "Released" %></th>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.pretty th .current {
  padding-right: 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}

.pretty th .asc {
  background-image: url(/images/up_arrow.gif);
}

.pretty th .desc {
  background-image: url(/images/down_arrow.gif);
}
```

Comment: The sorting you describe would best be implemented in Javascript, as it is fundamentally a client-side problem (whereas rails is there to help solve the server-side problems). The table sorter plugin for jquery is exactly what you're looking for: http://tablesorter.com/docs/.

Comment: Hi @Reck, thank you for the recommendation. I want to explore the possibility of doing this with rails, as a learning process.

Comment: What would be the default sort on the list of products that you want ??

Answer (score 6):

You should check out Ransack. It does a great job for sorting and complex searches. There is a great [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack) video that should help you and is much less invasive.

Comment: As of the moment, ransack does not work with edge RoR.  https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/polyamorous/issues/6

Comment: Try adding this to your gem file if you're having issues with `polyamorous`. `gem 'polyamorous', github: 'activerecord-hackery/polyamorous'`

Comment: `gem "ransack", github: "activerecord-hackery/ransack", branch: "rails-4.1"`   
`gem 'polyamorous', github: 'activerecord-hackery/polyamorous'`

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone will find this question. There is a a great gem for sortable columns (and not only that): https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid

Just look at the examples:
http://wicegrid.herokuapp.com/

Comment: The gem is not actively maintained anymore. The author mentions that he won't work on it and it's looking for maintainers.

Comment: There's a Rails 5 fork of it.  So if you're worried about using it not being maintained, the lack of maintenance by the original author is no longer a major concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can try placing an if check on the index method

```
def index
  if sort_column and sort_direction
    @products = Product.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  else
    @products = Product.all()
  end
end

def sort_column
  Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : nil
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : nil
end
```